# Capturing hash routes using google analytics in Angular 5 application

Tags: angular, google-analytics, routes

All of my application route is based on "/#/". For example "/#/home", "/#/contact" and so on . Nut all I see in my google analytics is "/" route. Which means it's dumping my hash routes following "#". Is there any way to capture those routes on my google analytics? Thank you all in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution, You can just fire

`gtag('config', 'YOUR_ID' , {
          'page_path': location.pathname + location.hash
      });`

by subscribing to route.events which will fire the above code every time the routes changes

Answer (score 0):

It is recommended to use the HTML 5 style (PathLocationStrategy) as location strategy in Angular. Don't use Hash Location Stratergy.

**Because**

1) It produces the clean and SEO Friendly URLs that are easier for users to understand and remember.

2) You can take advantage of the server-side rendering, which will make our application load faster, by rendering the pages in the server first before delivering it the client.

Use **Hashlocationstrtegy** only if you have to support the older browsers.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. I am aware of those fact pretty well. My site has SSR and all. But I have my reasons for using this method. Could you please help me if you know any way I can track my hashed routes in google analytics?